# iterate over array of objects using map

Tags: javascript

I want to iterate over an array of objects and pass wach object to a new array.

But the result is always the last object.

```
obj = [{ text: 'a'},{ text: 'b'}];
obj.map(funktion(item){
    result.push(Ext.merge({xtype: 'button'}, item));
});

// result is twice with text:'b'
```

It's always the last item. How dies this work?

Ext.merge simply merges two objects, same as JavaScript merge.

EDIT 1:
so I changed to

```
obj = [{ text: 'a'},{ text: 'b'}];
btnsDest = obj.map(function(item){
     return Ext.merge({xtype: 'button'}, item);
});
```

Still the same. btnsDest[i].text is always 'b'

EDIT 2:
so I actually had the following and tagt did not work

```
button = { xtype: 'button'};
obj = [{ text: 'a'},{ text: 'b'}];
btnsDest = obj.map(function(item){
     return Ext.merge(button, item);
});
```

So adding the var button to the callback did the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within the `map`'s callback function you need to return the transformed value (`mapped`):

```
obj = [{ text: 'a'},{ text: 'b'}];
obj.map(function(item){
    return Ext.merge({xtype: 'button'}, item);
});
```

---

Following is what I tried at my end with `node` and it works:

```
function merge_options(obj1,obj2){
    var obj3 = {};
    for (var attrname in obj1) { obj3[attrname] = obj1[attrname]; }
    for (var attrname in obj2) { obj3[attrname] = obj2[attrname]; }
    return obj3;
}

button = { xtype: 'button'};
obj = [{ text: 'a'},{ text: 'b'}];
btnsDest = obj.map(function(item){
         return merge_options(button, item);
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(btnsDest));
```

Output is:

```
[{"xtype":"button","text":"a"},{"xtype":"button","text":"b"}]
```

Comment: Aarrrrg. I defined button as an object outside the callback and used button inside the callback merge. That does not work.

Comment: did that work? I am posting something which I tried with node at my end and it works.